# Strange results from the denoiser

Tags: cycles-render-engine, denoise

I am working with a render, which shouldn't be that hard on the denoiser, nevertheless, well, I think this image says enough:

[image]

This render was after a hundred samples, and the noisy render it is based on doesn't look that crazy noisy to me:

[image]

So far I think I have tried every denoiser option there is. Openimagedenoise, optix, albedo, albedo and normal, none, cpu render, gpu render (cuda), accurate, fast. I don't think I have tried every possible combination of those options, but I have tried a lot of them, and the results are always very similar. Also, my normals look fine.

Edit: add blend file

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the blend file so we can further troubleshoot this problem? Use [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com)

Comment: I have edited the question, adding the blend file (I don't think the environment texture I used for lighting got included, but the result seems to be visible without that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured it out. It had something to do with the "Is camera ray" output in your "Light Path" node for the world shader and im not sure what. When I disconnected that, the noise in the final render basically disappeared and the weird blotchiness in the viewport disappeared. I think you need a different node setup for the world shader.

**Result in viewport (default world shader)**
[image]

**Result in Render (default world shader)**
[image]

Side note: if you want faster renders, change your render tile size to "256" px. You can change this setting in **"Render Properties > Performance Section > Memory Section > Tile Size"**

(mine is set to "384" but 256 is the most optimal value)
[image]

It makes a HUGE difference :)

Comment: That is very interesting, Kinda sad though, I kinda liked that little trick of getting nice natural lighting with a different background. Would this be considered a bug worth reporting?

Comment: That depends. Has is worked before? If it has worked before than it's not a bug and it just has something to do with something else in the project. If it hasn't, then you should probably report it. Perhaps you could try a different set up to get the same result. I hope you found the tip I left useful by the way. Happy I could help

Comment: wouldn't it be more of a bug if it did work before but doesn't now? Also, thanks to the tip, but it doesn't seem to do much on my system, I think tiling adjustments for speed improvements are somewhat hardware dependent.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Then I guess it would be a bug. You need to try again in a new blend project. Without anything else. Just the default cube and the world shader. If it works, that means it's something in your main project